# Unable to start eclipse kepler without root

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I have ask the same question in the ubuntu forum as well.

[unable to start ubuntu without root](http://kubuntu.com/questions/422378/unable-to-start-eclipse-kepler-without-root)

I am using eclipse Kepler on ubuntu 13.10 with java 8 and I am facing following error while starting without root.

[image]

Comment: It's odd that it would be trying to create a lock in /opt, did you use that as a workspace or project directory?  Anyway, if you have *ever* run a tool as root, you may have an old lock file around owned by root, which you can't clean up as a normal user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as root, try

```
 chmod -R +rx /opt/eclipse 
 chmod -R 777 /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager
```

If that doesn't work, try removing, the .manager, and repeat

Comment: as @chris pointed out, it's a bit unusual to be in this situation. You might find that you experience other problems in the future, eg. when installing plugins or updating. If so, repeat the chmod 777 higher up the path.